# Magento 2 - Add a Custom Button to header.phtml

Tags: magento2

My name is Costin and I am a beginner Magento 2 developer.
I have a question regarding on

How to add a button to **header.phtml** and to be displayed on the frontend?

What I have done until now:

- I create a basic module in

> /app/code/Vendor_Name_Module_Name

- Copied the file

> vendor/magento/module/theme/view/frontend/templates/html/header.phtml
>   into
>   /app/code/Vendor_Name_Module_Name/theme/view/frontend/templates/html/header.phtml.

what I want to achieve is :
[image: add button]

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Any luck on showing the button ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this to your **default.xml** theme layout (inside the header.links) .

```
<referenceBlock name="header.links">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="button.link"  before="-">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">BUTTON</argument>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">buttonpath</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
```

Or create a cms block , if you want to display a socia media icon for example https://d.pr/free/i/RcbmCO

and in the default.xml add this inside header.links block

```
 <referenceBlock name="header.links">
        <!--added social media links-->
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="social.media" before="-">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">social_media</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock><!-- end header.links -->
```

Comment: Thanks Ylgen, your answer helped me a lot .

Comment: @Costin Glad it helped :)

Comment: i want to add my url on button.please tell how it done?