# Magento 2 - Add button to the Header links

Tags: magento2, layout, cms, porto-theme, headerlink

I am trying to add a button called "social media" to be beside the Storeview switcher.
I tried to follow the answer in: [Magento 2 - Add a Custom Button to header.phtml](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/248887/magento-2-add-a-custom-button-to-header-phtml)

So I  created a CMS block on the backend called 'social media' with id 'social_media'.

I also add the following to the:
`app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Smartwave_Porto/layout/default.xml` file:

```
<referenceBlock name="header.links">
    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="social.media" before="-">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">social_media</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

However, it didn't work.

So my question: what is the right way to add such a button to the header links in magento 2.3.5 ?

Comment: check this out once: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/323537/51548

Answer (score 0):

> **app/design/frontend/[Package]/[Theme]/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="top.links">
           <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="button.link" before="-">
             <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">social_media</argument>
            </arguments>
           </block>
        </referenceContainer>

        <move element="button.link" destination="top.links" before="-" />

    </body>
</page>
```

screen shot attached.

[image]

Hope this will help you. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

You can add this to your default.xml theme layout.
at app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <referenceBlock name="header.links">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="button.link"  before="-">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Custom Button</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">path</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </page>
```

Output : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lg9yN.png

flush the layout cache.
Thanks!